# Custom HTML for Breadcrumb

Tags: navigation

What is the best way to create custom HTML for a breadcrumb (like SiteMapPath)?

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more what you want to achieve?

Comment: I see the a standard SiteMapPath will give me a lot of <span>s and a custom PathSeperator, wrapped around another <span>. But what if I want to add a class to the first and last span (beside the wrapping one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Googleing I found this:
http://johanleino.wordpress.com/2009/01/11/hiding-the-rootnode-in-a-breadcrumb-control-sitemap-path/
And by using `<NodeTemplate>`, `<RootNodeTempalte>` and CssClass I was able to solve my problems.
In `<RootNodeTemplate>` I could even add `<img />` to my HTML

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a custom Control to emit the html the way you want and add it in the PageLyout

Comment: So the best way to make custom HTML on existing constrollers in SP 2010 is to use Custom Control? Should I maybe extend SiteMapPath or something similar then?

Comment: I guess this is the answer then